# Make a sentence for/ on/ with

Tags: prepositions

I want to write a short instruction for a sentence-making exercise.

The student gets a list of words and he or she has to come up with a sentence for each single word. Personally, I think "for" is the best preposition. However, if I am not mistaken, I have heard a native speaker using "on" in situations like this. She said, "I asked her to make a sentence on XYZ".

Which one is the most suitable?

1. Make a sentence on every single word provided below.
2. Make a sentence for every single word provided below.

Comment: If a native speaker said "Make a sentence *on* _____", she probably meant "on the topic of _____", not "using the word _____".

Comment: Create or write a sentence using each of the following words. No for, no on, and no with either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter, (2), is the best option here.

You know this, even though you do not explicitly realize it. Look at the first sentence you just wrote as part of this question. You say "The student gets a list of words and he or she has to come up with a sentence ***for*** each single word."

You answered your own question in your first sentence.